# MySQL SET value with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to set a particular value to the last row in a table, but I'm not sure how to do this with subqueries. I am getting the sid of the last row in the table by

```
SELECT sid ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

and I want to assign "bar" to the foo column of that sid.

This is what I have so far, but it does not work (#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery').

```
UPDATE table SET foo="bar" WHERE sid IN (SELECT sid ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you specify the exact query? I would like to see the table names in select and update queries

Comment: Why so kurious? I'd rather not specify them unless that somehow helps you answer my question.

Comment: Because I wanted to check if you are reading and updating the same table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery at all. :)

```
UPDATE `table` SET `foo` = 'bar' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I'm back in the office.